# General Solution of Differential Equation with Substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of xy' + y = ${\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

So, I've tried using u=$\frac{y}{x}$, and that gets me to a point where I have.

$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}-2u}du$ = $\int\frac{1}{x}dx$

The right side I know how to solve, I just have no idea what to do with this integral on the left.

Comment: You can use one of many online calculators, for example http://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/integral-calculator/

Comment: This one is also with all steps, but unfortunately in german. Perhaps one can understand it nevertheless. https://www.integralrechner.de/

Comment: As for this concrete problem. You can extend with $\sqrt{1+u^2}+2u$ and then substitute $u=\tan(v)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{t \equiv \root{1 + u^{2}} - u \implies u = {1 - t^{2} \over 2t}}$:

\begin{align}
\int{\dd u \over \root{1 + u^{2}} - 2u} & =
\int{\dd t \over t} - {2 \over 3}\int{2t \over t^{2} - 1/3}\,\dd t =
\ln\pars{\verts{t}} - {2 \over 3}\ln\pars{\verts{t^{2} - {1 \over 3}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\ln\pars{\verts{\root{1 + u^{2}} - u}} -
{2 \over 3}\ln\pars{\verts{\pars{\root{1 + u^{2}} - u}^{2} - {1 \over 3}}}
\end{align}
$$
= \bbx{\ln\pars{\verts{\root{1 + u^{2}} - u}} -
{2 \over 3}\ln\pars{\verts{2u^{2} + {2 \over 3} -2u\root{1 + u^{2}}}}
+ 
\pars{~\mbox{a constant}~}}
$$